# O(n) takes more time than O(nlogn)

Tags: c++, caching

I was trying [this](http://www.spoj.pl/problems/GONESORT/) problem on spoj.
First of all I came up with a sort of trivial o(blogb) algorithm(refer the problem for whats b).But since the author of the problem mentioned the constraints as b belongs to [0,10^7] i was not convinced if it would pass.Anyways out of shear belief I coded it as follows

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<iostream>
#include<algorithm>
#include<cmath>
#include<vector>
#include<cstdlib>
#include<stack>
#include<queue>
#include<string>
#include<cstring>


#define PR(x) cout<<#x"="<<x<<endl
#define READ2(x,y) scanf("%d %d",&x,&y)
#define REP(i,a) for(long long i=0;i<a;i++)
#define READ(x) scanf("%d",&x)
#define PRARR(x,n) for(long long i=0;i<n;i++)printf(#x"[%d]=\t%d\n",i,x[i])
using namespace std;
#include <stdio.h>
struct node {
          int val;
          int idx;
          };

bool operator<(node a,node b){ return a.val<b.val;}
node contain[10000001];
int main(){
          int mx=1,count=1,t,n;
          scanf("%d",&t);
          while(t--){
                count=1;mx=1;
                scanf("%d",&n);
                for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
                        scanf("%d",&contain[i].val);
                        contain[i].idx=i;
                        }
          sort(contain,contain+n);
          for(int j=1;j<n;j++){
                    if(contain[j].idx>contain[j-1].idx)
                            count++;
                            else count=1;
                            mx=max(count,mx);
                                }
                    printf("%d\n",n-mx);
                    }
                   }
```

And it passed in 0.01 s on SPOJ server(which is known to be slow)
But I soon came up with an O(b) algorithm,code given below

```
 #include<stdio.h>
    #include<iostream>
    #include<algorithm>
    #include<cmath>
    #include<vector>
    #include<cstdlib>
    #include<stack>
    #include<queue>
    #include<string>
    #include<cstring>


    #define PR(x) printf(#x"=%d\n",x)
    #define READ2(x,y) scanf("%d %d",&x,&y)
    #define REP(i,a) for(int i=0;i<a;i++)
    #define READ(x) scanf("%d",&x)
    #define PRARR(x,n) for(int i=0;i<n;i++)printf(#x"[%d]=\t%d\n",i,x[i])
    using namespace std;
    int val[1001];
    int arr[1001];
    int main() { 
    int t;
    int n;
    scanf("%d",&t);
    while(t--){
            scanf("%d",&n);
            int mn=2<<29,count=1,mx=1;
            for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
                    scanf("%d",&arr[i]);
                    if(arr[i]<mn) { mn=arr[i];}
                    }
            for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
                    val[arr[i]-mn]=i;
                    }
            for(int i=1;i<n;i++){
            if(val[i]>val[i-1]) count++;
            else {

            count=1;
            }
            if(mx<count) mx=count;
            }
            printf("%d\n",n-mx);
            }
    }
```

But surprisingly it took **0.14s** :O

Now my question is isn't **o(b) better than o(blogb) for b > 2** ? Then why so much difference in time? One of the members from the community suggested that it may be due to cache miss.The o(b) code is less localized as compared to o(blogb).But I dont see that causing a difference of **0.10s** that too for <1000 runs of the code? (Yes b is actually less than 1000.Dont know why problem setter exaggerated so much)

**EDIT** : I see all answers are going towards the hidden constant values in asymptotic notations that often cause disparity in the running times of algorithms.But if you look at the codes you will realize all I am doing is replacing the call to **sort** by another traversal of the loop.Now I am assuming sort accesses each element of the array atleast once .Wouldn't that make both programs even closer if we think in number of lines that get executed?Beside yes my past experiences with spoj tells me I/O makes drastic impact on the running time of the program but I am using the same I/O routines in both the codes.

Comment: Please fix the indention. Nobody will answer when you use obscure code formatting like this.

Comment: Big-O notation is asymptotic.

Comment: @BrettHale: If he had to ask, that probably didn't mean a thing.

Comment: @KendallFrey - I don't know how to put it any more succinctly.

Comment: Wouldn't your O(n) thing crash and burn due to `val[arr[i]-mn]=i;` if the serial numbers aren't consecutive? Like `1 10^6 (2*10^6)`?

Comment: @DanielFischer It will....But the problem statement constraints states that they will be consecutive.The fact that the code passed on the online judge seconds that

Comment: I just re-read the problem statement, I see no such constraint. The sample inputs strongly suggest it, though, so it's a gamble one might well take.

Comment: last line states "2nd line wil contain b numbers. each bi denoting the serial number of the book".Since bi are the serial number of books I assumed them to be consecutive.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Big O notation describes how long the function takes as the input set approaches infinite size. If you have large enough data sets, O(n) will always beat O(n log n).

In practice, some 'poorer-performing' algorithms are faster because of the other hidden variables in the big O formula. Some more scalable algorithms can be slower. The difference becomes more arbitrary as the input set becomes smaller.

I learned all this the hard way, when I spent hours implementing a scalable solution, and when testing, found that it would only be faster for large data sets.

Edit:

Regarding the specific case, some people mentioned that the same line of code can vary extremely with regards to performance. This is likely the case here. That means that the 'hidden variables' in the big O formula are very relevant. The better you understand how a computer works on the inside, the more optimization techniques you have up your sleeve.

If you only remember one thing, remember this. Never compare two algorithms' performance by just reading the code. If it's that important, time an actual implementation on realistic data sets.

Comment: @kendall But all I am doing is replacing the call to sort function by another traversal.I am assuming sort will make atleast 1 traversal.So in terms of number of lines executed both programs must be similar?The hidden variables in this case would be present in the o(blogb) code too

Comment: @bashrc: sure the O(n) is only one traversal, but at each index it's a virtually guaranteed cache miss, so it will run _much_ slower than each traversal of the quicksort, which has very few cache misses.  Each traversal can take 60 times longer if it has to go all the way to RAM, over 2000x slower if it pagefaults.

Comment: some off the cuff math suggests your one traversal is 450x slower than each quicksort traversal.

Comment: @MooingDuck I was suspecting the same thing.I had mentioned it in my original question too.But everyone seems to be bent on the asymptotic nature of big O notation.

Comment: @MooingDuck Quoting from my original question "One of the members from the community suggested that it may be due to cache miss.The o(b) code is less localized as compared to o(blogb)"

Comment: @bashrc: yes, the hidden constant in the big O notation (450ish) is cause by cache misses.  They are directly relaated.

Answer (score 4):

I/O operations (`scanf()`, `printf()`) are biasing the result.

those operations are notoriously slow and show a great discrepency when timing them. you shall never measure the performance of code using including any i/o operations, unless those operations are what you are trying to measure.

so, remove those calls and try again.

i will also point out that 0.1s is very small. the 0.1s difference may refer to the time it takes for loading the executable and preparing the code for execution.

Comment: @adrien 0.1s was still accepatable.The difference comes out to be 0.10 s?that's 10 times more

Answer (score 3):

Big-O notation isn't a formula that you can plug arbitrary values of `n` into.  It merely describes the growth of the function as `n` heads to infinity.

Comment: You and I have had this discussion before, haven't we?  You convinced me last time that you were right, and I remain still convinced.  (I have answered as I have here in light of the specific question asked.)

Comment: Totally agree.But I have edited my question slightly in order to make myself more clear.

Answer (score 1):

This is a more interesting question than one might suspect.  The O() concept can be useful, but it is not always as useful as some think.  This is particularly true for logarithmic orders.  Algebraically, a logarithm really has an order of zero, which is to say that log(n)/n^epsilon converges for any positive epsilon.

More often than we like to think, the log factors in order calculations don't really matter.

However, Kendall Frey is right.  For sufficiently large data sets, O(n*log(n)) will eventually lose.  It's only that the data set *may* have to be very large for the logarithmic difference to show.

Comment: @MooingDuck:  The feedback is appreciated.  What if I write, "In theory, one can posit a data set so large that even a good O(n*log(n)) algorithm is outperformed a poor O(n) algorithm.  It's only that...."  Does such wording address your concern, or did you have something else in mind?

Answer (score 0):

I looked at your solutions in SPOj. I noticed that your O(nlogn) solution takes 79M memory while O(n) takes very small amount of memory which it shows as 0K. I looked at the other solutions too. Most of the fastest solutions I looked at used a large amount of memory. Now the most obvious reason I can think of is the implementation of `std::sort()` function. Its very nicely implemented which makes your solution amazingly fast. And for the O(n) solution i think it may be slow because of `if() {...} else {...}`. Try changing it to ternary operators and let us know if it makes any difference.

Hope it helps !!

Comment: if i dont consider cache miss than for std::sort() to beat my O(n) must do it in less than 2*n steps.No matter how fast sort() is I seriously doubt if it beats the single traversal thing for an random array.I still doubt the culprit is cache misses.